# Python function to draw random numbers based on chosen distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, optional-parameters, normal-distribution

I am writing a function that will draw random numbers from a given distribution like Poisson, Normal or Binomial. It takes one argument for number of samples and a second argument for type of distribution. It would accept additional parameters based on the distribution chosen. So if I take Normal samples then its mean and sd.

Is there an optimal way of writing this?

My code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def randNumberDistribution(samples, distribution,*optional):
    if distribution.capitalize() == 'Normal':
        if len(optional) == 2:
            mean, sd, = optional
            s = np.random.normal(mean, sd, samples)
            print(s)
            count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 20, density=True)
            plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),linewidth=3, color='y')
            plt.show()
        else:
            print("Invalid number of arguments")
    if distribution.capitalize() == 'Binomial':
        if len(optional) == 2:
            numOfTrials, probSuccess = optional # number of trials, probability of success(each trial)
            s = np.random.binomial(n, p, samples)
            count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 14, density=True)
        else:
            print("Invalid number of arguments")
    if distribution.capitalize() == 'Poisson':
        if len(optional) == 1:
            exp = optional
            s = np.random.poisson(exp, samples) #Expectation of interval(should be >= 0)
            count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 14, density=True)
        else:
            print("Invalid number of arguments")


print(randNumberDistribution(5,'Poisson',5))
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you get an error when you call your function inside print?  Because, as is, its not returning anything and is actually printing things in some of your if and else blocks

Comment: @BilalSaleem no I don't get an error when I call my function inside print

Comment: @BilalSaleem If a function doesn't explicitly return anything then it will return `None`, therefore there won't be an error when calling a function in a print

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of things like dictionaries or Classes but IMHO, I find your code simple and easy to understand. I would just make use of `elif` to avoid checking all the `if` statements once a condition is satisfied. Below is a slightly short version. Your `else` statements were specific for a given distribution type. Mine simply checks for the 3 cases and says invalid for any other input.

```
def randNumberDistribution(samples, distribution,*optional):
    if distribution.capitalize() == 'Normal' and len(optional) == 2:
            mean, sd, = optional
            s = np.random.normal(mean, sd, samples)
            count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 20, density=True)
            plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),linewidth=3, color='y')
            plt.show()
    elif distribution.capitalize() == 'Binomial' and len(optional) == 2:
            n, p = optional # number of trials, probability of success(each trial)
            s = np.random.binomial(n, p, samples)
            count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 14, density=True)
    elif distribution.capitalize() == 'Poisson' and len(optional) == 1:
            exp = optional
            s = np.random.poisson(exp, samples) #Expectation of interval(should be >= 0)
            count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 14, density=True)
    else:
        print("Invalid number of arguments")
```